# ehcache configure from a file

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, configure

This is probably a silly question but I am trying to configure ehcache form the xml file in a java class. I have the ehcache.xml in the "/src/main/resource" and I am configuring in a java class at "/src/main/java/com/.../xyzDAO.java"

```
CacheManager cm     =   CacheManager.create("CLASSPATH:ehcache.xml");
cache               =   cm.getCache("mycache");
```

It says that the file cannot be found. Is this the right way to configure ehcache in the first place?

Please suggest.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc for `CacheManager.create(String)` isn’t very comprehensive. But if this method works like the `CacheManager(String)` constructor, it expects a full pathname. If you want to use a file found in the classpath, I suggest you use another `create` methode, like `CacheManager.create(URl)` or `CacheManager.create(InputStream)`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me:         InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ehcache.xml");
                
        CacheManager cm  =  CacheManager.create(in);

Comment: Glad I helped you. Don’t forget to close the InputStream after creating your CacheManager.